Show that $\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-\gamma\right)e^{-\gamma|t|}=-2\gamma\delta(t)$
the problem just says "show the relation $\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-\gamma\right)e^{-\gamma|t|}=-2\gamma\delta(t)$. Hint: a step function may be useful in the proof"
I'm not sure if the problem has a typo or something, since it's not even saying what I'm taking the derivative of, and it's not clear if $\gamma$ is a constant. The $\delta(t)$ in this question is the usual Dirac-delta function.
If this is a result anyone has seen before, some guidance on what it's saying and how to go about showing this relationship would be appreciated.
Thanks

My interpretation is the derivative is with respect to $e^{-\gamma|t|}$ which isn't a smooth function at $t=0$ but can be evaluated as $e^{-\gamma |t|}=e^{\gamma t}+\theta(t) \left(e^{-\gamma t}-e^{\gamma t}\right)=e^{\gamma t}+\frac{1}{2} (\text{sgn}(t)+1) \left(e^{-\gamma t}-e^{\gamma t}\right)$.

@bears Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

I think there is a typo. The correct formula should be
$$ \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} - \color{red}{\boxed{\gamma^2}}\right) e^{-\gamma|t|} = -2\gamma\delta(t). $$
Indeed, using the fact that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}|t| = \operatorname{sgn}(t)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\operatorname{sgn}(t) = 2\delta(t)$, we get
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} - \gamma\right) e^{-\gamma|t|}
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} e^{-\gamma|t|} - \gamma^2 e^{-\gamma|t|} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} [(-\gamma\operatorname{sgn}(t))e^{-\gamma|t|}] - \gamma^2 e^{-\gamma|t|} \\
&= \left[ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (-\gamma\operatorname{sgn}(t)) \right] e^{-\gamma|t|} + (-\gamma\operatorname{sgn}(t)) \left[ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} e^{-\gamma|t|} \right] - \gamma^2 e^{-\gamma|t|} \\
&= -2\gamma \delta(t) e^{-\gamma|t|} + \gamma^2 e^{-\gamma|t|} - \gamma^2 e^{-\gamma|t|} \\
&= -2\gamma \delta(t),
\end{align*}
where in the last step we utilized the fact that $\delta(t)f(t) = \delta(t)f(0)$ for any continuous function $f(t)$.

This makes sense!
Thank you!

The expression $\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}-\gamma^2\right)e^{-\gamma|t|}=-2\gamma \delta(t)$ means that for any function $\phi\in C_C^\infty$, we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{-\gamma|t|}-\gamma^2e^{-\gamma|t|}\right)\,dt=-2\gamma \phi(0)\tag1$$
To show that $(1)$ is true, we first integrate by parts (twice) to find that
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{-\gamma|t|}-\gamma^2e^{-\gamma|t|}\right)\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\gamma|t|}\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\phi(t)-\gamma^2 \phi(t)\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{\gamma t}\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\phi(t)-\gamma^2 \phi(t)\right)\,dt\\\\
&+\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\gamma t}\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\phi(t)-\gamma^2 \phi(t)\right)\,dt\tag2
\end{align}$$
Next, we integrte by parts (twice) the two terms on the right-hand side of $(2)$ to reveal
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)\left(\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{-\gamma|t|}-\gamma^2e^{-\gamma|t|}\right)\,dt&=\left(\phi'(0)-\gamma \phi(0)\right) +\left(-\phi'(0)-\gamma \phi(0)\right)\\\\
&=-2\gamma\phi(0)
\end{align}$$
And we are done!

@bears Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.
